# Sampling from a dataframe and having to find proportions

Tags: r

I am quite beginner at R and I was hoping someone could guide me with this question.

I have a data frame that tells me whether 2,000 individuals voted or not. I have to sample 100 individuals and then find what proportion of them voted.

To do that, I decided to assign a number to each individual to differentiate them and do the sample. After that, however, I don't know how to add the variable to know whether they voted or not. Here is what I did:

```
vote$assignment <- c(1:2000)
  
sample <- sample(vote$assignment, 100, replace=F, set.seed(100))

sample100 <- as.data.frame(sample)
```

First lines of the dataframe:

```
 vote  assignment
   1         1
   1         2
   0         3
   1         4
   1         5
   1         6
   0         7
   1         8
   1         9
   1         10
```

Any ideas of how I get to that dataframe the information of whether they voted or not?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you dput a few lines of original DataFrame?

Comment: The `dplyr` package has a function, `slice_sample()` which allows you to do this easily enough: `dplyr::slice_sample(mtcars, n = 10)`.

Comment: I've added the code @Divyansh.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have 1/0 values in `vote` column where 1 is for the people who voted and 0 for the people who have not voted.

You can randomly select 100 individuals and take `mean` of `vote` column to get percentage of people who voted.

```
#Assign unique id's for each row
vote$assignment <- seq(nrow(vote))
#Selected random 100 rows
selected_rows <- sample(nrow(vote), 100)
#Get the percentage of people who voted.
percent_voted <- mean(vote$vote[selected_rows]) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used the `dplyr` solution as suggested by Phil.  Or you can consider the `base` solution.

```
# the data
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2000)
df$vote <- sample(c(1, 0), 2000, replace = TRUE, set.seed(123))

# the sampling
samp_id <- sample(df$id, 100, replace = FALSE)

df_vote <- df[samp_id, ]

       id vote
225   225    0
1279 1279    0
1585 1585    1
946   946    1
1578 1578    0
1481 1481    0
651   651    1
1601 1601    0
354   354    1
203   203    0

prop <- mean(df_vote$vote)
prop
```